# How to store radio buttons in an array in android

Tags: android, arrays, radio-button

How to store radiobuttons object in an array and then check their state?
I have a list of questions and yes or no answers implemented with radio buttons and i have to count the "yes" answers

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Hashmap where you will store radiobutton object as key and its state as value.

Thanks
Michiru

Comment: Could you please give me an example ? I need to count the "yes" answers.   I'm kinda new to Java and I can't seem to find a simple example. So  I have a list of questions with yes or no answers the radiobuttons ids are r1 r2 ...etc and the text is yes or no . How do I count them?